# Couldn't connect to the primary server: postgresql HA installation

Tags: rhel, postgresql, replication, high-availability

Trying to install `Postgresql-9.4 High Availability (HA)` in `RHEL7`, using three nodes. In all three nodes, installed `postgresql`, updated `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` files accordingly. After completing all configurations, tried to check verify the synchronous streaming replication by using the command in Master server

```
select * from pg_stat_replication;
```

It returns

```
postgres=# select * from pg_stat_replication;
 pid | usesysid | usename | application_name | client_addr | client_hostname | client_port | backend_start | backend_xmin | state | sent_location | write_
location | flush_location | replay_location | sync_priority | sync_state
-----+----------+---------+------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-------+---------------+-------
---------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+------------
(0 rows)
```

Which shows, there is no replication. When I was looking into the postgresql log files, I found the connection is not being established from standby nodes to the Master node. The log files in all three nodes looks like,

Node 0:

```
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "x.x.x.x (node1)", user "postgres", SSL off
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "x.x.x.x (node2)", user "postgres", SSL off
```

Node 1 and Node 2:

```
FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: 
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "x.x.x.x (node0)", user "postgres", SSL off
```

To check the connection, I've disabled iptables in all three nodes. Able to ping from/to all other nodes, telnet from slave to master works and from master to slave doesn't work. Not sure, why it happens (even when iptables service is stopped).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the master node (node 0): update the `pg_hba.conf` file, add `postgres` (user) to access the database.

In the standby nodes (node1 & node2): disable `iptables` or configure `firewall` to accept connections to and from master.

In /etc/sysconfig/iptables, add below lines and restart.

```
 -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5432(port) -j ACCEPT
 -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

This solution resolved my issue.